# Magento Multisite links go to wrong domain

Tags: url, magento1.9.3, base-url, magento-1.9.3.10

I have created a new website within my Magento **(1.9.3.10)**
I've created a home page and got the menu visible.
When you click on a Menu item, it links to my other website domain, showing a 404.

I have checked (and rechecked!) the Base URLs and they are all correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered there was an error in the `.htaccess` file code.
**Should be:**

```
## SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store ##
SetEnvIf Host .*my_domain1.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=website_code_for_my_domain1
SetEnvIf Host .*my_domain1.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```